# How to redirect multiple times after submitting form with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to show the result of movie query.

When I submit my form, I am correctly redirected to to page with the result. The problem is, if I enter a new movie's title and submit again, I'm not redirected anymore (so don't see the new result). I have to refresh the browser to see the result.

My Home vue.

```
<template>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" v-on:submit.prevent="submit()">
    <input
      class="form-control mr-sm-2"
      type="search"
      v-model="query"
      autofocus
      placeholder="Enter a movie title"
      aria-label="Search"
     />
     <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
              Search
            </button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      query: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log('clicked')
      this.$router.push({ name: "search-movies", query: { q: this.query } });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

My Search vue (the result page)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <MovieListItem v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id" :movie="movie" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MOTService from "@/services/MOTService.js";
import MovieListItem from "@/components/MovieListItem.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MovieListItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      movies: [],
      meta: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    searchMovies() {
      MOTService.searchMovies(this.$route.query)
        .then(response => {
          this.movies = response.data["data"];
          this.meta = response.data["meta"];
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("There was an error:", error.response);
        });
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.searchMovies();
  }
};
</script>
```

My router.js

```
...
{
  path: "/search",
  name: "search-movies",
  component: Search,
}
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean with "if I submit again with a different result"

Comment: @Flame The problem is, if I enter a new movie's title and submit again, I'm not redirected anymore (so don't see the new result)

Comment: hm the `submit` function should be called again, check for that. Then the router should direct you to the correct page. I cant imagine what is going on here

Comment: @Flame I added a console.log to check if the method is called again and yes. But I'm not redirected

Comment: are you still on route search-movies when you did your second search?

Comment: @ChrisLi Yes it is

Comment: your only running searchMovies on create, if your not creating Search your not requesting any new data

Comment: @ChrisLi You're right... Do you have any idea how can I do a new request even if I am on the same page?

Comment: one way is to use events

Answer (score 0):

As said Chris, if I'm already on the route `search-movies`, I am not doing a new request, so I can't update the result.
My easier solution is to add `this.$router.go(0);` on the `submit()` function.

```
...
methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$router.replace({ name: "search-movies", query: { q: this.query } });
      this.$router.go(0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a watcher on your `$route.query` and refetch the search anytime the query changes:

```js
methods: {
  searchMovies(query) {
    MOTService.searchMovies(query)
      //...
    });
  }
},
created() {
  this.searchMovies(this.$route.query);
},
watch: {
  '$route.query'(value) {
    this.searchMovies(value)
  }
}
```